# Multiplying two fractions with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, factoring

I'm doing
$$
\frac{6-7i}{1+i}\cdot\frac{1+i}{1+i},
$$ and I'm getting the correct value for the numerator (namely, $-1-13i$), but based on the problem answer, I need for the denominator to become $2$. However, $(1+i)^2\neq 2$. How can I write the denominator as a real number?

Comment: (1+i)(1+i) must = 2?

Comment: Yea. I'm doing $(6-7i)/(1+i)$ x $(1+i)/(1_i)$ and I have the result's top to $-1 -13i$, and the bottom that I get needs to be 2.

Comment: Is i referring to an imaginary number or is it a variable?

Comment: Imaginary number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to write
$$
\frac{6-7i}{1+i}
$$ in the form $a+bi$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$. We can multiply this fraction by $1 = \frac{1-i}{1-i}$ in a clever way:
$$
\frac{6-7i}{1+i}\cdot\frac{1-i}{1-i} = \frac{(6-7i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}.
$$ The numerator works out to
$$
(6-7i)(1-i) = 6-6i-7i+7i^2 = -1-13i,
$$ while the denominator works out to
$$
(1+i)(1-i) = 1+i-i-i^2 = 1-(-1) = 2.
$$
In this problem, you want to get rid of the $i$ in the denominator; in other words, given $a+bi$ you want to find $c+di$ such that $(a+bi)(c+di)$ is just a real number (no $i$ term). This is easily accomplished by setting $$c+di = \overline{a+bi} = a-bi,$$ the complex conjugate of $a+bi$. Then
$$
(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2+bi-bi-b^2i^2 = a^2+b^2.
$$ However, if you were to take $a+bi$ and compute $(a+bi)^2$, like you were trying to do, then you would obtain
$$
(a+bi)(a+bi) = (a^2-b^2)+2abi.
$$ But then $2ab\neq 0$ unless $a=0$ or $b=0$. So unless you're lucky, doing
$$
\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\cdot\frac{c+di}{c+di}
$$ won't work so well to simplify that denominator.

Comment: @Infinity, yes they asked if $(1+i)^2=2$... but their update makes it clear that they meant $(1+i)(1-i)$.

Comment: @windy401: Did you mean $(1+i)(1-i)$ as in my edit?

Comment: No, unless I've been doing all the other problems wrong and still getting the right answers, then it should be 1+i, just like in the denominator of the 6-7i part. I'm doing division of these, the $6-7i/1+i$ and I got the numerator of the answer right, am trying to find the denominator, and the boom says it should be 2.

Comment: @windy401 does the update help?

Comment: Hmm. So in this case the sign needs changed to -. All the other problems I did it had to be kept the same. What's going on here? How do I know when to change it?

Comment: That all makes sense. I'm just confused because every other problem I've done before this, the sign has been the same, like in this it was 1+i in the denominator of the first part, but you changed it to -. In the other problems I've done like this it's stayed the same.

Comment: @windy401: how's that?